# bash script to extract jar file and copy the path

Tags: java, bash, shell

I am a PhD student of software testing. I made a script to test all the classes in a specific folder. However to make it fully automatic I would need a script that extract all the jar files in a respective folder and copy both the paths before and after extracting the jar file. For example

If I have AAA.jar at location /Users/mian/Systems/AAA.jar and AAA.jar on extraction create the folders and class org/apple/orange/banana.class then I would like to separately assign org/apple/orange/ to variable VAR1 and /Users/mian/Systems/org/apple/orange/ to VAR2.

The script I have so far is this

```
#!/bin/bash

 STR1="/Users/mian/QualitasCorpus/Systems/freecs/freecs-1.3.20100406/bin/freecs-1.3.20100406/lib/"
 STR2="freecs.commands."

     for i in $( ls $STR1 ); do
         if [[ $i == *.class ]]
         then 
         echo " @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ The Class under test is "$i" @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@" >> result.traces
         java yeti.YetiWithDaikon -java -time=10s -nologs -ADFDPlus -testModules="$STR2${i%.*}" >> result.traces
         echo " %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% The Class is finished testing %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%" >> result.traces
         fi
     done
  echo "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"  >> result.traces
  echo "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ End of Folder @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"  >> result.traces
  echo "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"  >> result.traces
  mv result.traces resultsOf"$STR2"traces
```

Comment: what is issue? where you stuck?

Comment: At the moment I am manually updating STR1 and STR2. I need to extract the jar file and then the full path to STR1 and additional path to STR2. For example in the above case the jar file is freecs.jar. I extracted it manually which forms 2 folders i.e. freeces/commands/foo.class and the total path is/Users/mian/QualitasCorpus/Systems/freecs/freecs-1.3.20100406/bin/freecs-1.3.20100406/lib/freecs/commands/

Comment: @Asbat While extracting these jar-s do you get these paths printed in output, if yes you can filter these paths from there and provide them as cmdline parameters to this script and then you shall never have to work Manually :D

Comment: Yes, when I apply jar -xvf abc.jar I get the path printed in output. How can I assign it to the variable? Can you please give me the code? thanks.

Comment: Don't parse ls: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: If you edit the question to show us how you currently obtain STR1 and STR2, we can help you automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

This script writes info about the jar file. Names of variables are included in echo.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
STR1=$(dirname $(realpath $1".jar"))
unzip -qo $1".jar" -d $1 #unzip jar file to working_directory/jarname/
list=$(tree $1 -Rnfi --noreport | grep ".class") #gets the raw .class file list
list=$(echo $list | sed -e 's/'$1'\.//g') #removes the first foldername
list=$(echo $list | sed -e 's/\/class//g') #removes the last .class
list2=$list
list=$(echo $list | sed -e 's/\//\./g') #changes / to .
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'" "
echo -e "STR1=\033[34m"$STR1"\033[0m\n"
echo -e "FOLDER=\033[31m"$1"\033[0m\n"
for STR2 in $list
do
    echo -e "STR2=\033[32m"$STR2"\033[0m"
done
echo ""
for STR3 in $list2
do
    echo -e "STR3=\033[33m"$STR3"\033[0m"
done
echo ""
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Usage:

You have a jar file called freecs.jar. Run it with:

```
SCRIPTNAME jarfilename
```

without the `.jar` extension.